# jqueryUI conformation dialog Disappears

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, submit

Can someone help with the jQueryUI dialog box that I am trying to get to work for a confirmation yes or no

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 240,
                modal: true,
                show: {
                    effect: "blind",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 1000
                },
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $('#searchForm').submit();
                    },
                    "No": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        return false
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        $(function () {
            $('#searchForm').submit(function () {

                $("#dialog").dialog("open");

            });
        });
</script>


    <div id="dialog" title="Confirm Terms?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Click YES to accept the Terms of Use</p>
</div>
       <form action="#" id="searchForm" method="post" name="searchForm">
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname" style="width: 140px;" type="text" value="paul" />
            <input id="surname" name="surname" style="width: 140px;" type="text" value="east" />
            <input id="address" name="address" style="width: 490px;" type="text" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" />

                  </form>
```

Every time I click the submit button the dialog box appears for about 1 second then disappears and submits the form. Please can you point to where I am going wrong

[I have ran it in jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DFNET/8/)

thanks Paul

Answer (score 2):

The dialog is immediately disappearing because your submit function does not `return false` or have a `preventDefault()` call. See:

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Without this, the form submission will automatically happen after your dialog is shown.

**Edit:**

In addition, when submitting your form in your dialog Yes button handler, you're going to be calling your submit function again, which will immediately re-show the dialog - probably not what you want!

You'll have to store the user's confirmation before calling submit on the form. For example:

```
var reallySubmit = false;

...

buttons: {
    "Yes": function () {
        reallySubmit = true;
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $('#searchForm').submit();
    },

...

$('searchForm').submit(function () {
    if (!reallySubmit) {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    }
});

...
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly. And thanks for the edit I'm sure that would of been my next question